# Permanently converting tuples to lists in Python

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, tuples

```
>>> t=(0,0,3)
>>> t
(0, 0, 3)
>>> list(t)
[0, 0, 3]
```

That looks like the tuple was converted to a list but then when I print the tuple `t`:

```
>>> t
(0, 0, 3)
```

I realize nothing has happened. Am I missing anything or this is how it works in Python 2.6.5?

Comment: You'll need to assign it to `t` again; `list()` returns a new list.

Comment: @akaIDIOT why not make that an answer… since it is one.

Comment: It's important to realise that running functions on data which cause side effects to that data usually isn't a good thing.

Comment: Idk why this got downvoted so aggressiveness  :(

Comment: My guess is because its a fairly easy thing to google.

Comment: @Hopdady: This is what Google said to me: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples
Please look at the "Conversions" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = list(t)
```

`list(t)` returns a new list while keeping `t` as a tuple.

Think about a case you want to have both tuple and list.

```
t2 = list(t)
```

t is still a tuple while t2 is now a list.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `t = list(t)`.  list(t) *returns* a list

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, just assign back to `t`:

```
t = list(t)
```